# count the same character if it comes next

Tags: string, python-2.7, list

```
 def check(input):



mylist = list(input)

    print mylist

    position = 0

    total = 0

    count = {}

    while position < len(mylist):

        if mylist[position] == mylist[position + 1]:
            # print mylist[position]
            total = total + 1
            count[mylist[position]] = total
            print count
            if mylist[position] != mylist[position +1]:
                total = 0
            if mylist[position] == len(mylist) - 1:
                break

        position = position + 1

    print count


check("aabbbbccbdad")
```

I would like to count the same character, if it comes next. For example for this sample input, the output should be like that;
count = {"a":2, "b":4, "c":2, "b":1, "d":1, "a":1, "d":1}

I got IndexError in the list. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: You have IndexError because you are checking  `mylist[position +1]` which will be out of index in last loop iteration. You should edit your code (def is outside code).
You should also make counting rule clearer. I don't understand why you have "d:1", what about 'b:1','d:1','a:1' and 'd:1'?

Comment: Hi @alex-baranowski yes that would be added on the dict as well. just wanted to show a sample output.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
groups = groupby(s)
result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
result
```

input :

```
s = 'aabbbbccbdad'
```

Output :

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 2), ('b', 1), ('d', 1), ('a', 1), ('d', 1)]
```